# How to unit test (in memory) entity framework?

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework, poco

As in the topic...

I was thinking about something like "in memory changes".
On recent blogs by Jaroslaw Kowalski i have found similar approach
but i was thinking about sth much simpler

Comment: Please provide more context.  Perhaps a language tag, link to what "entity framework" is, etc...

Answer (score 2):

If the framework consists of (abstract) classes, you can create dummy concrete classes and unittest them.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are building/modifying the framework itself, you shouldn't need to unit test it.

As for unit testing entity classes you define, I would recommend the following.
1. Create a stub implementation that uses an [in memory database](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InMemoryTestDatabase.html). Which will allow you to test class interaction. 
2. Design you classes in such a way that business logic does not require the Entity Framework and unit test those directly.